# How to upload multiple files to AWS S3 in Java using aws-java-sdk version 2?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How to upload multiple files to AWS S3 using `aws-java-sdk` version 2?

I can use a for-each loop and `s3Client.putObject(requestConfig, requestBody);`, but is it possible to achieve this without using a loop, I mean just call one method and pass a list of files there (something like `s3Client.putObjects(/* some args */);`)?

And another question, if it is possible to upload multiple files to AWS S3 without using a loop, can it be done in a transactional way so that all files or none of them are uploaded?

This is how I'm doing it right now, but is this the right approach?

```
    public void upload(String key, String mimetype, byte[] content) {
        var bucket = this.configurationManager.getAwsConfig().getBucketName();

        var requestConfig = this.preparePutObjectRequest(key, mimetype, bucket);
        var requestBody = RequestBody.fromBytes(content);

        this.s3Client.putObject(requestConfig, requestBody);
    }

    public void batchUpload(List<UploadFileBO> files) {
        for (UploadFileBO file : files) {
                this.upload(file.getKey(), file.getMimetype(), file.getContent());
            }
        }
    }

    private PutObjectRequest preparePutObjectRequest(String key, String mimetype, String bucket) {
        return PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .key(key)
                .contentType(mimetype)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: The [underlying S3 APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html) have no concept of a transaction or a way to upload multiple objects at once.  It's an oft requested feature for the SDKs to add one, but anything they add would look much like your code, and operate as a convivence just uploading multiple objects separately as a.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the S3 Transfer Manager? It has some methods for working with multiple files, such as [UploadDirectory](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html).  There is an example of working with it in the [Example Code Library here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_UploadDirectoryToBucket_section.html).

```
public Integer uploadDirectory(S3TransferManager transferManager,
                                   String sourceDirectory, String bucketName){
        DirectoryUpload directoryUpload =
            transferManager.uploadDirectory(UploadDirectoryRequest.builder()
                .source(Paths.get(sourceDirectory))
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build());
```